# AVPlayer fails with error "Segment exceeds specified bandwidth for variant"

Tags: avplayer

This is on Mac 10.9 and 10.10.

I have strange issue here. I am doing HLS playback on Mac. When I start the streaming, the first segment id (which is 100) is requested and playback starts. The playback continues fine for another 15-20 mins and then it fails with following avplayer error log

`#Version: 1.0
Software: AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.14A389 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_10; en_us)
Date: 2014/11/10 15:50:21.021
Fields: date time uri cs-guid s-ip status domain comment cs-iftype
2014/11/10 15:35:18.018 http://localhost:12000/stream/content.ts?id=192.168.1.165-8f1ad93ec6ce651f2d22&bps=1200000&segid=100 791DF980-68C1-43D4-A294-EB88BAD3DBF5 127.0.0.1 -12318 "CoreMediaErrorDomain" "Segment exceeds specified bandwidth for variant" -`

The last segment that was requested from AVPlayer was segid=468 when plyaback failed.

I don't understand why the player is complaining about segid=100 which was played 20 mins back?

Could he error message be misleading?

I am out of ideas. Any hint would be helpful.

Thanks
D

Comment: Same issue with exact same error description on iOS 8.x.

Comment: I remember the error logs are aggregated, which means you will not get the error log right away, but after it's aggregated. Please check WWDC to confirm my impression.

Answer (score 3):

If the issue is still actual.
The error is misleading,because you get it after playing chunck with segId equal to 100. It means what it describes.

After 15 minutes there are no new errors in player's log. You just have one, original.

Comment: No need to vote down this answer; the error described is indeed misleading. The thing is a log and that is a log entry, that log entry does not necessarily relate to error(s) that just happened.